# Scanf() don't read number 0 or read is wrong

Tags: c, scanf

Hello I have a litlle problem. I trying to make a bank wait time program but the time i read a 0 value with scanf() it do not read or read wrong. I did some search but noting that solves my problem.

this is the code.. its in C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int c, n, t,i,d;//entradas do usuário (caixas, usuários, momento de chegada, tempo de atendimento
int menor_espera=0;// caixa de menor tempo de espera
int tempo_maximo = 20;// tempo maximo de espera por atencimento
int resultado=0;//Numero de pessoas com mais de 20 minutos de espera por atendimento

scanf(" %u %u %*c\n", &c, &n);// Lê o numero de caixas, numero de clientes no dia
if(c>0 && n>0){//iniciação só com valores positivos e possiveis c>1, n>1 (1 caixa e um cliente)
    int caixa[c];// declara o um vetor de caixas
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){// Loop de numero de usuários
    scanf(" %u %u %*c\n", &t, &d);//Lê um cliente (T e D)
    printf("print: %u %u\n", c, n);
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<c;j++){// loop de caixas
            if(caixa[j]<caixa[menor_espera]){//chaca se o caixa atual é o primeiro caixa disponivel (caixa com menos tempo de uso)
                menor_espera = j;//positivo, atualiza o caixa de menor espera
            }
        }if(caixa[menor_espera]-t>tempo_maximo){//checa se o cliente terá de esperar mais que o tempo maximo para ser atendido baseado na sua chegada
            resultado++;//positivo, atualiza o contador de usuário que esperaram mais que o tempo maximo
        }caixa[menor_espera] += d;// atualiza o tempo de uso do caixa que foi utilizado
    }
    printf("Resultado final: %d\n", resultado);// exibe resultado final
}getch();
```

}

and this is a input

```
1 16
0 10
0 10
0 10
3 10
5 10
7 10
11 10
13 10
14 10
15 10
16 10
17 10
18 3
19 10
20 10
23 3
```

that's the output i have

```
print: 10 0
print: 0 0
print: 0 3
print: 0 5
print: 0 7
print: 0 11
print: 0 13
print: 0 14
print: 0 15
print: 0 16
print: 0 17
print: 0 18
print: 19 10
print: 0 10
print: 3 3
print: 3 3
Resultado final: 16
```

but it shoud'nt look like this.

Tks for any help. if i found the solution i'll post here.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that you are not capturing or testing the return value from `scanf()`.  It returns the number of items it parsed, or -1 on an i/o error.

Consider something like this to at least find out if this might be a problem:

```
if (scanf(" %u %u %*c\n", &t, &d) < 2)  //Lê um cliente (T e D)
     printf ("input conversion or i/o error\n");
```

Comment: Don't forget, the suppressed assignments are not counted; that will only produce `2` as a result.  You can never actually determine whether the `%*c` succeeds, or the `\n` (which actually matches more white space), except by seeing what is the next character after the scan completes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  good point.  I had not noticed the `*` until now.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is problematic:

```
scanf(" %u %u %*c\n", &c, &n);
```

It looks for two numbers, some white space, and a non-white space character that is ignored, followed by more white space (which may or may not be a newline).

Given your input file, the first `scanf()` reads:

```
1 16
0
```

The next character to be read will be the `1` of the `10` on the second line of data.  That's why you have problems.

Use `fgets()` to read a line at a time, and `sscanf()` to parse the line.  And test the results of both `fgets()` and `sscanf()` (or `scanf()` if you insist on using it).

Here's an approximation to what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, n, t,d;
    int menor_espera = 0;
    int tempo_maximo = 20;
    int resultado = 0;
    char line[4096];

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        if (sscanf(line, "%u %u", &c, &n) != 2)
            return(1);
        if (c > 0 && n > 0)
        {
            int caixa[c];   // VLA - uninitialized
            for (int i = 0;i < n; i++)
            {
                if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
                    break;  // EOF or error
                if (scanf(line, "%u %u", &t, &d) != 2)
                    break;  // EOF or error
                printf("print: %u %u\n", c, n);  // Not t and d??
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
                {
                    // Accessing uninitialized data in caixa array!
                    if (caixa[j] < caixa[menor_espera])
                        menor_espera = j;
                }
                if (caixa[menor_espera] - t > tempo_maximo)
                    resultado++;
                caixa[menor_espera] += d;
            }
            printf("Resultado final: %d\n", resultado);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I think there are some logic errors in the original code (some highlighted with comments), but I'm not sure what the corrections should be.